# Define a ThreadingLayer involving list

Tags: neural-networks

As part of a larger net I am trying to define a `ThreadingLayer` but this results in an error:

```
NetGraph[
  <|"w" -> ThreadingLayer[{122, 128, 134, 140}[[#1]] + {168, 174, 180, 186}[[#1]] (1 + Tanh[#2]) &]|>, 
 {{NetPort["d"], NetPort["v"]} -> "w"}, "Output" -> 4, "d" -> 4,  "v" -> 4]
(* During evaluation of In[151]:= ThreadingLayer::invscf: {122,128,134,140}[[#1]]+{168,174,180,186}[[#1]] (1+Tanh[#2])& could not be symbolically evaluated as a n-ary scalar function.
During evaluation of In[151]:= NetGraph::netinvnodes: $Failed is not a layer, a net, or a valid specification for one.    
$Failed *)
```

The offending bit seems to be `List`; for instance, this works fine:

```
NetGraph[
  <|"w" -> ThreadingLayer[#1 + #1 (1 + Tanh[#2]) &]|>, 
 {{NetPort["d"], NetPort["v"]} -> "w"}, "Output" -> 4, "d" -> 4,  "v" -> 4]
```

Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining suggestions by @flinty and from support:

```
lower = {122, 128, 134, 140};
upper = {168, 174, 180, 186};

NetGraph[<|
  "lowerList" -> NetArrayLayer["Array" -> lower, LearningRateMultipliers -> 0], 
  "upperList" -> NetArrayLayer["Array" -> upper, LearningRateMultipliers -> 0], 
  "lower" -> ExtractLayer[], "upper" -> ExtractLayer[], 
  "w" -> ThreadingLayer[#lower + #upper   (1 + Tanh[#v]) &]|>, 
  {{"lowerList", NetPort["d"]} -> "lower" -> NetPort["w", "lower"], 
   {"upperList", NetPort["d"]} -> "upper" -> NetPort["w", "upper"]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround. The problem is you can't use `Part` / `[[ ]]` in there, but you can construct a `Piecewise` function that returns those numbers, for input 1,2,3,4...

```
NetGraph[<|"w" -> ThreadingLayer[
    (x |-> Piecewise[{{122, x <= 1}, {128, x <= 2}, {134, x <= 3}}, 140])[#1]
  + (x |-> Piecewise[{{168, x <= 1}, {174, x <= 2}, {180, x <= 3}}, 186])[#1]*
        (1 + Tanh[#2]) &]|>, {{NetPort["d"], NetPort["v"]} -> "w"}, 
 "Output" -> 4, "d" -> 4, "v" -> 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works; however it is not super convenient in my real setup as the function is more complex. I had tried defining `f[n_, x_] = 
 Piecewise[{{122, n <= 1}, {128, n <= 2}, {134, n <= 3}}, 140] + 
  Piecewise[{{168, n <= 1}, {174, n <= 2}, {180, n <= 3}}, 
    186]*(1 + Tanh[x])` and using `f` in the net returns the same error.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what yes, you have to define the function within the layer. It seems you can't use an external function. However, have you looked at using a constant layer with: `NetArrayLayer[{122,128,134,140}, LearningRateMultipliers->0]` and then using `PartLayer` or `ExtractLayer` ? That might be more reasonable than using a big piecewise here.